# Need to move folder and contents if first charcter matches list

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have been using a great little batch FOR loop to do some tedious steps, and would like to modify it to do more, but can't find the right approach to use in any examples.

Here is what I have now:

> for /f "delims=*" %%i in (Move_Test.txt) do   move
>   "E:\07-All_Books\%%i" E:\08-SF_Books\ >nul 2>&1

I hope this formatting makes sense, but it does work ok. Anyway the file "Move_Test.txt" contains a list of authors names. The loop scans the "07-All_Books" directory and looks for matching folder names in that directory. If a match is found, it moves that folder the "08-SF_Books directory.

What I need to do is to modify this to something similar, but doing a single character comparison.

The file "Move_Test.txt" now has only the letters A-Z, one letter per line.

I want the loop to:

1. Read each line in the "Move_Test" file and compare the **first letter only** of folders in the "All_Books" directory.
2. If a match is found, that matching folder will be moved to a directory that has 26 A-Z folders with name structure of "Authors - A", "Authors - B", and so on through Z. So, if a match for the first letter "B" was found, that folder would be moved into the directory "Authors - B", and so on.

I am stuck on doing that first letter only comparison (upper or lower case) and then taking that letter variable into the correct move-to folder.

And, if there is a cleaner way to eliminate the "Move_Test" text file, I am certainly open to that as well.

Answer (score 0):

To check if the first letter matchs, reffer to the files as:

```
[letter]*
```

Or:

```
%%i*
```

For your case. The wildcard `*` would make the program look for every character after the letter you put forward. So in terms of your code:

```
for /f "delims=*" %%i in (Move_Test.txt) do move "E:\07-All_Books\%%i*" E:\08-SF_Books\ >nul 2>&1
```

Also, I don't think you require the `"delims=*" if there is only one character per line. Mona

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
FOR %%A IN (
    A B C D E F
      G H I J
      K L M N
      O P Q R
      S T U V
      W X Y Z
      ) DO (
ECHO MOVE "E:\07-All_Books\%%A*" "E:\08-SF_Books\Authors - %%A"
)
```

Remove the `echo`, if the output looks good.

Comment: Sorry getting back to check the forum! I will give these a try; both answers look great!